# Git Clone only gets the master branch

Tags: git

When I `git clone`, it seems I only get the `master` branch.

There is a number of branches for this repo on BitBucket.
However after cloning, if I check for other branches using `git branch -a`, the command executes without errors but there's no output.
The same goes for `git fetch --all` / `git pull` ... .
Therefore I cannot checkout to any specific branch.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "git branch -a, the command executes without errors but there's no output." I don't believe that. It should list the master branch at least!

Comment: Please show how you cloned.

Comment: `git --no-pager branch -a` ?

Comment: I git cloned as follows:
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.domain:1111/a/b.git

Comment: @phd, git --no-pager branch -a also executes but shows nothing

Comment: What if anything do you get if you run `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` after cloning? (Showing nothing at all for `git branch -a` after `git clone` would be normal for a repository with no commits in it, but not for one that has commits and branches. Note: `git fetch --all` is a command you should never run *yet*. Someday, maybe, but before then, learn about `git remote update`.)

Comment: git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch also executes without output... .

Comment: Does `git rev-parse HEAD` have any output?  If not, your installation/environment is just broken.

Answer (score 0):

> I git cloned as follows:
>
> ```
> git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.domain:1111/a/b.git
> ```

Then cd to `b/` (the folder created by the `git clone`), and type:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch
git branch -avv
```

Check if you see any other (remote tracking) branches after that.

Comment: I struggle to understand how this worked but it did! I now see all the branches, thank you very much